# Session variables are getting reset on payment gateway redirect on chrome and edge browsers

Tags: php, google-compute-engine, lamp

On one of my websites, I observed that the session variables are getting reset on a payment gateway redirect on the chrome, edge and opera browsers.

What I have already done:

I contacted chrome and edge (basically Google and Microsoft for the issue) and yet to hear back from them.

I have contacted the payment gateway providers and am yet to hear back from them.

I have checked my website code and verified and reverified that it is not a coding issue as it works on Safari and Firefox browsers.

Based on my research online I was suggested by some sections online that it is a same-site issue.

The same-site fix is already there in my server as part of a htaccess file as below:

<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-3]|iPad; CPU OS 1[0-3]|iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-3]|Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X.*Version\x2F1[0-3].*Safari|Macintosh;.*Mac OS X 10_14.* AppleWebKit.*Version\x2F1[0-3].*Safari)/i">
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure

Any help in fixing this issue would be hugely appreciated.

Note: I thought it was a server-specific issue as it has to do with htaccess so I initially posted on server-fault, but it appears my question was banned as spam! My best guess is that the moderators were drunk:) with all due respect to them!

The above fix works in my local though!

Existing fixes for a similar issue were not able to solve the problem at hand.

My config uses php 7.0

Comment: Check the `SameSite` attribute of your session cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: @CBroe the same site fix is already implemented in my server as If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-2]|iPad; CPU OS 1[0-2]|iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-2]|Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X.*Version\x2F1[0-2].*Safari|Macintosh;.Mac OS X 10_14. AppleWebKit.*Version\x2F1[0-3].Safari)/i"> Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure </If>

Comment: Have you verified it is actually set in the Set-Cookie header the client receives?

Comment: And why is this wrapped into a user agent check? It should be set for all clients. (Older ones that don’t know the meaning of the SameSite attribute yet, should simply ignore it.)

Comment: That is based on a suggestion from Apple https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181